# How to reduce the time in dynamic addition of rows and columns to TablelayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am interested in reducing the time of adding rows and colums to tablelayoutpanel dynamically.

I need to add 10 rows and 10 columns (maximum 10x 10 =100 controls, may be less than 100 depending upon user input), I have construct the logic which works good but the problem of my logic is it's taken considerable time in adding rows and columns to tablelayoutpanel.

```
    for (int rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= (TSegments.Value); rowNumber++)
    {
        for (int columnNumber = 1; columnNumber < (PSegments.Value) * 2 + 2; columnNumber++)
        {
            tempTextBox = new TextBox(); 
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tempTextBox, columnNumber, rowNumber);
            tempTextBox.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right; 
            tempTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
```

Comment: for (int rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= (TSegments.Value); rowNumber++) { for (int columnNumber = 1; columnNumber < (PSegments.Value) * 2 + 2; columnNumber ++) { tempTextBox = new TextBox(); tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tempTextBox, columnNumber, rowNumber); tempTextBox.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right; tempTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

Comment: tempTextBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                    tempTextBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                    tempTextBox.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    tempTextBox.AutoSize = false;
                    tempTextBox.Height = 37;
                    tempTextBox.Width = 50;

Comment: Asad: Add the code to the Question, this is unreadable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best/only way to speed it up is by surrounding the changes with  Suspendlayout/ResumeLayout. Just call yourtable.Suspendlayout() before changing the table and ResumeLayout() after it.

Comment: Could you please further elaborate it? Its new to me 'Suspendlayout/Resume:ayout.

Comment: @Asad: just call yourtable.Suspendlayout() before changing the table and ResumeLayout() after it.